# Handlebars render html with the template

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I have an html content in context which will be passed to handlebars template.
I expect the html to render seamlessly, but it doesn't. Is there a way to render pre-compiled html?

I have tried in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agoyal/uocLgyn0/1/, the rendering is not perfect.

This is the html template:

```
<script id="document-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div>

    <p>container 5</p>
    <div>{{{data}}}</div>

</div>
</script>
```

Comment: I removed all your code in your fiddle and kept only the var context delaration. It display something even if is only declared in the script. Something is wrong with the data otherwise it should display something blank.

Comment: @ChristopheThiry The data contains script tags and style tags along with the HTML. I hope handlebars can render such data.

Comment: It is but even if it renders data your data alone render something on screen already that will disrupt anything that you will render. Try to clean your data so that just declaring it as var does not render something first.